# Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate

Tags: reactjs

am trying to toggle the state of a component in ReactJS but I get an error stating:

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I don't see the infinite loop in my code, can anyone help?

ReactJS component code:

```
import React from 'react' 
    
import Buttonevent from './buttonevent.js'
    
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {counter: 0};
  }
    
  clickHandler() {    
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter+1
    }, function () {
      console.log (" Job done");
    });  
  }
  
  render() {
    return(   
      <div classname="app">  
        <div classname="click-count">
          Button presses: {this.state.count}
        </div>
    
        <button onClick= {this.clickHandler.bind(this)}> Add one</button>
    
        <Buttonevent></Buttonevent>
    
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Button;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
class Buttonevent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { buttontext: "Click me Please"};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
    
  handleClick() {
    this.setState(() => {
      return { buttontext: "Thanks, Button has been clicked !"}
    });
  }
        
  render() {
    const {buttontext} = this.state
    return <button onClick ={this.handleClick()} > {buttontext} </button>    
  }
}
export default Buttonevent;
```

Answer (score 1):

The below line of code is your problem

```
return <button onClick ={this.handleClick()} > {buttontext} </button>
```

The function is getting called because of this.handleClick() instead it should be like below

```
return <button onClick ={this.handleClick} > {buttontext} </button>
```

Comment: thank you for sorting out the issue.   can you check is there any problem with the class Button.  I'm not getting the counter output

Comment: @Sasikumar S The variable name in render is incorrect.
Instead of:  Button presses: {this.state.count}
Use: Button presses: {this.state. counter}